Не работает python в VSCode
Только скачал питон. Написал обычный принт с хеллоу ворлдом. Запустилось только при нажатии кнопки "Запуск файла пайтон" в код раннере. Изменил код на просто хеллоу. Также пишет хеллоу ворлд. короче работет код только при нажатии этой кнопки.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Так работает или не работает? В вашем вопросе нет самого вопроса. Что и как должно происходить по вашему? Какой результат и от каких действий/кода ожидается?

@SwaD сам код раннер не хочет запускать код нормально. Это получается только при нажатии другой кнопки. Это не очень удобно.

В расширении code runner нет необходимости. По моему опыту от него больше проблем. Для запуска кода достаточно "стандартного" расширения Python.
